# "The URL you entered is considered unsafe and may not be used" message appears when I try to register an Instagram New App or Client

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I get message

> The URL you entered is considered unsafe and may not be used, or you
>   have been making too many changes

When I try to register New Client for https://tochkafamily.ru site on Instagram Developer console.
However I do not get such message if I enter any other URL instead. What it might be? How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The same happened for me. Check the website in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/.
You may try giving a feedback to Facebook, and I believe, Instagram uses the same database. No guarantee that your website will be white-listed. I've tried a couple of sites previously without any success.